# Python Merge Sort Stuck in Infinite Loop

Tags: python, algorithm, mergesort

I am preparing for job interviews so I am trying out medium leetcode questions. I looked up a LL merge sort solution and recreated it fine in the leetcode editor, but hit a problem implementing it myself in VSCode. It is getting stuck in an infinite loop in the getMiddle() function. I tried stepping through it with a debugger but can't identify where the problem is.

```
# node class 
class Cat:
    def __init__(self, name="", next=None):
        self.name = name
        self.next = next

# linked list class
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
   
    def pushCat(self, new_name):       # add new node to beginning of LL
        newCat = Cat(new_name, None)
        
        if self.head is None:          # if LL empty, set new node to head 
            self.head = newCat

        else:
            newCat.next = self.head   
            self.head = newCat

    # split list down to individual elements
    def sortList(self, head):

        if not self.head or not self.head.next:
            return self.head

        left = self.head
        mid = self.getMiddle(self.head)
        right = mid.next
        mid.next = None

        left = self.sortList(left)
        right = self.sortList(right)

        return self.mergeList(left, right)
    
    # merge list
    def mergeList(self, list1, list2):
        dummy = tail = Cat()

        while list1 and list2:
            if list1.name < list2.name:
                tail.next = list1
                list1 = list1.next
            else:
                tail.next = list2
                list2 = list2.next
            tail = tail.next

        # append any extra elements
        if list1:
            tail.next = list1
        if list2:
            tail.next = list2
        
        
        return dummy.next      #return head



    def getMiddle(self, head):
        slow, fast = head, head.next
        while fast and fast.next:
            slow = slow.next
            fast = fast.next.next

        return slow
    

    def printList(self):
        curr_node = self.head
        while curr_node:
            print(curr_node.name, end = " ")
            curr_node = curr_node.next
        print("\n")



# create linked list, push 3 new cats, and call sortlist() function to mergesort alphabetically.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    li = LinkedList()

    li.pushCat("Roland")
    li.pushCat("Billy")
    li.pushCat("Caesar")

    head = li.head
    print(head.name)

    print("Before sort: ")
    li.printList()          # Caesar Billy Roland
    li.sortList(head)
    print("After sort: ")   # expected: Billy Caesar Roland
    li.printList()          # actual: stuck in infinite loop in getMiddle() function
```

If anyone can easily identify the problem I would appreciate it.

Comment: Assuming none of the other methods can introduce a cycle, I don't see how `getMiddle` could get stuck in an infinite loop. `fast.next` will eventually become `None`, either making the loop condition false or causing `fast.next.next` to raise an `AttributeError`.

Comment: `mid = self.getMiddle(self.head)` - should this be `mid = self.getMiddle(head)` ? i.e. in your recursive calls, you want the middle of the sublist that was passed to the function as the parameter, not the middle of the list that `self` represents. Similarly, should the line above that be `left = head` ?

Comment: change `self.head` to `head` in `sortList` function's condition and statement. You are always referring to the main head, not the sublist's head.

Comment: You're getting stuck because at some point in your code `"Caesar.next = Caesar" which creates the infinite loop in getMiddle(). I have yet to identify where this is happening.

Comment: @Zero after sorting one needs to assign a new value to `self.head` somehow.

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit, *somehows* are the issues mate.

Comment: OP, check [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort-for-linked-list/) out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues:

- `sortList` is not using its `head` argument. All references it has to `self.head` should be `head`
- `sortList` never modifies `self.head`, yet it could well be necessary.

We could say your code is mixing up linked list instances with chained nodes. In `sortList` you call methods that actually don't work on the linked list instance, but only on nodes (even though `getMiddle` and `mergeLists` are defined as methods on `LinkedList`, they don't bother about `self`).

I would clean this up and move methods to the `Cat` class when they don't intend to work on linked list instances, but only on nodes. So you would end up with `sort`, `merge`, and `getMiddle` methods on `Cat`. The `sortList` method on the `LinkedList` class would then call the `sort` method on the `Cat` class, and take its returned head node to assign it back to the `self.head` attribute.

With some other improvements, your code could be corrected to this:

```
class Cat:
    def __init__(self, name="", next=None):
        self.name = name
        self.next = next

    def __iter__(self):  # useful for printing and other stuff
        while self:
            yield self.name
            self = self.next

    def sort(self):
        if not self.next:
            return self
        mid = self.getMiddle()
        right = mid.next
        mid.next = None
        return self.merge(self.sort(), right.sort())

    @staticmethod
    def merge(head1, head2):
        dummy = tail = Cat()
        while head1 and head2:
            if head1.name < head2.name:
                tail.next = head1
                head1 = head1.next
            else:
                tail.next = head2
                head2 = head2.next
            tail = tail.next
        tail.next = head1 or head2  # shorter syntax
        return dummy.next

    def getMiddle(self):
        slow, fast = self, self.next
        while fast and fast.next:
            slow = slow.next
            fast = fast.next.next
        return slow


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
   
    def pushCat(self, new_name):
        newCat = Cat(new_name, None)
        # simplified code
        newCat.next = self.head   
        self.head = newCat

    def sortList(self):
        if self.head:
            self.head = self.head.sort()    

    def __repr__(self):
        return " ".join(self.head)  # This relies on __iter__


if __name__ == '__main__':
    li = LinkedList()
    li.pushCat("Roland")
    li.pushCat("Billy")
    li.pushCat("Caesar")
    print("Before sort: ")
    print(li)  # don't print in methods. Instead rely on `__repr__` or `__str__`
    li.sortList()
    print("After sort: ")
    print(li)
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate that you not only explained the problem but included some best practices as well.